# Spring Cloud Data Flow - Is there a way to store the Arguments as part of Task?

Tags: spring-cloud-dataflow

I am using SCDF on k8s. When  run the task, every time I have to enter the Arguments and Parameters. Is there a way I can auto save them along with Task definition so that I dont need to enter every time?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By design, the task definition doesn't include the arguments or batch job parameters (if your task is a batch job). This is because the task arguments and parameters are bound to vary and typically provided externally. But, if you want them to be part of the task application, then you can have them configured as task application properties instead of arguments.